# Best method to associate a list of users in one mysql table

Tags: mysql, performance, list, datatable, store

I'm trying to associate a dynamic number of users to other users. Explain would be if you friend someone on Facebook. Their user becomes associated with yours as a friend. How do you store this in a MYSQL table? I do under stand that it's a many-to-many relationship, but from what I've been ready. When you JOIN two tables, it create a third that handles the PK from both original tables creating an associative table. My concern is that there could be a heavy amount of tables being created for few associations.

My primary example is:

```
primary_User: 1

list_of_other_Users: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

How do I get one table that is

```
1| 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

vs.

```
1|2; 1|3; etc...
```

Comment: Yes - you have a linking table. But you only need one linking table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern is not valid... for relational databases I suggest you to keep your design as it's described... I mean the table can be as heavy as possible and you don't need to worry about that. For the response of select you must optimize your DB (tables and queries). For InnoDB:

-[Optimizing for InnoDB Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb.html)

-[Optimizing InnoDB Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-queries.html)

As you can notice is a whole topic, but you can start by keeping the design as simple as possible and maybe using some [INDEXES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/create-index.html).